# Help creating an app with parsing

Tags: android, html-parsing

I'm working on my University thesis creating an android app. As I'm new in android development I would like to read your opinion on that.

I would like to create an app that has a home screen with n buttons. This will be the app for my uni forum. When I press the "announcement" button for example I want to get the announcements from my university site.

The problem is, that this site doesn't have a rss feed and but I want to see the announcements in the app and not with a `WebView`.

Could you please tell me what I have to search for? HTML parsing? Hope my question is understandable.

Comment: I hopefully improved your question without changing the meaning. Please take the next time a bit effort on your question style, the formating and the language itself @downvoters at least you could write why you vote this question down!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Web Scraping](http://www.codediesel.com/php/web-scraping-in-php-tutorial/)

Comment: this article creates a .php file.After i create it,where do i have to paste it in order to work with my android app?

Comment: That link was meant to be an answer and example of what needed to be done.  In order to apply it to your android application you will need to write something of the same nature in java.

Comment: is there any src for android use?

Comment: This may be more helpful for an android/java application. http://masochismtango.com/2010/02/15/webharvest-web-scraping-from-java/